# Is the RabbitMQ RPC a kind of "Work queue" with response?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

is the RabbitMQ **RPC** a kind of **Work queue** with response?
In the RPC description you can read:

> If the **RPC** server is too slow, you can scale up by just running another one. Try running a second `rpc_server.py` in a new console.

So in my mind **RPC** is a worker queue and every worker is responding if task is done. Or am I wrong?

Worker Queue: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-spring-amqp.html

[image]

RPC: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-spring-amqp.html

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The two chapter are different case for teach different things.

**Worker Queue** will teach you the concept of prefetch. You can set basicQos.

**RPC** show you the BasicProperties of message And the exclusive of Queue.

If you want to know more about basicQos/BasicProperties/etc, you can check the [api](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) or [spec](https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html).

You also can combine Work Queue and RPC together. You can append two or more server to consumer rpc_queue.

Comment: "You also can combine Work Queue and RPC together. You can append two or more server to consumer rpc_queue."


This is exactly the point I want to know. More than one server = "workers" are listening to same queue and just one server will take the message from the queue, process his work and send back to client? I totally understand that RPC and Worker Queue are different approaches which RabbitMQ offers. So if the behavior of RPC with more than one server is what i explained here one can say it is a kind of "mix" of RPC and Worker Queue?

Answer (score 0):

AMQP tutorial aims at giving you the tools to achieve common patterns using basic AMQP concepts. So keep in mind we're just commenting on the implementations from the tutorial and nothing else. You might choose to change the way it works on your side if it fits better to your need.

Consequently, there are similarities between those implementations, and you will use some of the tools from one step of the tutorial to another. For example, there is inherently one type of queue in RabbitMQ and you're using it from step 1 to step 6 of the tutorial. Similarly, the suggested implementations for RPC and for work queues both use a direct exchange.

But there are also differences. For instance, the work queue (as described in the tutorial) is non-exclusive (meaning it can be read and consumed by multiple connections/consumers), whereas the RPC tutorial declares its queues to be exclusive. More importantly, the RPC tutorial explains to you how to use the "reply-to" feature, and a correlation id to be able to implement the RPC pattern. Anyhow, you might always choose whether this is good for you or not.

RabbitMQ is not a "RPC" or "Work queues" framework. It gives you a set of tools to implement such patterns, but it's way more powerful than that. You have to understand the concepts and how they fit together to achieve those patterns, more than "how to achieve RPC with RabbitMQ" as a whole.

Hope this helps.